# How can I remove the letters “UTC” from the time in a column of cells with date and time entries?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, utc

I have cells in a spreadsheet with the date and time in `UTC` (over a thousand of them).

I want to remove the letters `UTC` as I need to import the document elsewhere and it doesn’t work with the letters `UTC`.

For example, I want to change this:

```
2021-03-04 0:51:31 UTC
```

To this:

```
2021-03-04 0:51:31
```

Comment: Ctrl f (brings up find window)... replace utc with nothing.

Comment: Of course!!! Brilliant, thank you so much ---that was so easy, to use Find & Replace (with nothing) in an instant @Isolated.

It worked

Answer (score -1):

I do not have a Microsoft Excel on my PC at the moment, so I can not try out any solution for Excel, but if it is a one-off problem you are trying to resolve, I would suggest you to use the following tool:

https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

1. Type in: "UTC" in the `Input Regular Expression` text field (without the quotation marks).
2. Paste your entire column with the dates in the text area.
3. Below the `Options` label, tick `Invert Match`.
4. Click the `Process text` button on the bottom of the form.

It will return with a new page containing your date column without the UTC postfix.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for offering this possible solution. Unfortunately it returned noting tin the form at all

Comment: You might have used a lower-case "UTC" pattern in the search bar. I would suggest you to use upper-case (exactly as it appears in your quoted example above) or tick the "Ignore case" in the options.

Answer (score -1):

Successfully answered by @Isolated. simply use the Find & Replace command (Ctrl+H) in Edit, Replace UTC with <nothing/leave blank> and 'all cells, or all sheets or formatted display' It worked for me

Comment: Please don’t answer your own question like this. Encourage the commenter who provided you with the answer to post the answer so they get credit for this.